# C++ how to convert ratio to double

Tags: c++

I need some constant and found that I can get it in the standard library ratio, but not directly. Suppose I want a double value one_nano, I can do this.

```
const double one_nano = (double)nano::num / nano::den;
```

But personally I don't believe that's better than this:

```
const double one_nano = 1e-9;
```

I just don't want to define the constant myself, is there something like nano::value or anything else?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with either approach (I'd pick the second without a thought). So, what exactly are you looking for that these two don't have?

Comment: If you look at a reference to e.g. [`std::ratio`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) you will see that they use a third variant.

Comment: @Fernandes Both are OK except that they need me to define it. Well, I will define it if I have no choice.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Could you point out the third variant, please. I tried Looking at the reference but didn't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a constant directly is more readable. If you think it's ugly, you could always just put it in a header rather than at the top of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`nano::value` is not a member of ratio class. only `nano::den` and `nano::num` members are available.

May be you can use division by nano::den instead of multiplying with `nano::value`[not available].

Or you can use a header file for defining your constants.

Comment: Division is much more expensive than multiplication.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes "May be you can use division by nano::den instead of multiplying with nano::value" This sounds like in a constant to you?